# CertificateFactory returns null with non-certificate input

Tags: java, x509certificate

I'm using `java.security.cert.CertificateFactory` to generate (from an `InputStream`), then verify a public certificate file. When I use a proper certificate file, ex `cert.cert` I get a proper certificate and can generate the fingerprint, use it for communication with a server, etc.


However, when I select files that are definitely **not** certificates, ex `settings.txt` I sometimes get a `CertificateException` and sometimes it actually `null`. I can't find a description of this behaviour for CertificateFactory, or any reasoning why some files cause `generateCertificate` to throw an exception vs. returning null.


My code in question:

```
CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(parameters.getCertificate());
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certificateFactory.generateCertificate(stream);
```

The last line will either return the exception, or cert will be null. My question is:

Why does certificateFactory.generateCertificate(stream) return null when a non-certificate file is given as input? Shouldn't it throw a CertificateException?

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be an interesting question. My reading of the [`CertificateFactory.generateCertificate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertificate-java.io.InputStream-) docs left one case unclear to me, what should be returned when the stream is positioned at EOF. I think it should generate an exception. I believe null should never be returned. The java.security.cert.CertificateFactory class itself simply delegates the [`generateCertificate()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.java#CertificateFactory.generateCertificate%28java.io.InputStream%29) call to an internal spi class. [OpenJDK8's implementation of this spi class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/security/provider/X509Factory.java#X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate%28java.io.InputStream%29) never returns null. This is also likely true for Oracle's implementation. Therefore, I must conclude that you are not using one of these implementations.

When I examined the [Bouncycastle provider's implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.52/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/x509/CertificateFactory.java#CertificateFactory.engineGenerateCertificate%28java.io.InputStream%29), I see it returns null in several places, including when EOF is reached. It is possible that Bouncycastle's implementation is non-compliant.

Comment: My class import is:

Comment: Well that's just embaressing. My class import is:
`import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;`
Am I not using Java's CertificateFactory?

Comment: Yes, you are but that class doesn't really do any of the work. See the source code I linked to in my question. Is this by chance running on Android?

Comment: Nope, this is a desktop application.